# Should I strictly use both DTOs and models in Angular project in order to follow best practice?

Tags: architecture, angular

I was reading [these best practices](https://angular-enterprise.com/en/ngpost/courses/best-practices/) for Angular project specifically for understanding models and DTOs.

What I have understood in general from different resources and the above one also is that

1. We should have DTO to match exact response structure coming from backend APIs
2. We should have model classes to use to show data on the pages and for other operations

The problem is if I follow this approach I will have to then write mapper also for all the DTO to model classes which seems unnecessary effort.

I can easily achieve everything without breaking any design pattern with having any one of DTO or model classes.

Should I follow the best practice to have both DTO and model with so much additional code which is not serving too much of a purpose or can I go with just models or just DTOs being used on all levels and my Angular design will not be considered a bad design?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744373/should-i-strictly-use-both-dtos-and-models-in-angular-project-in-order-to-follo "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: The issue with these things is always the same - people take the term "best practice" and confuse it with "dogma". Or this wording: *"breaking any design pattern"* - that's a mindset of design patterns as "rules" which can be broken, which is, allow me to say this, completely misguided. Do yourself a favor and whenever you see the term "best practice" next time, replace it by "rule of thumb" or "80% recommendation", whatever you like best.

Comment: ... Moreover, who the heck is the company behind "angular-enterprise.com"? They show no impressum at their site, and WHOIS only tells me they are siiting in France, every other information is blocked. What kind of authority do they have on "best practices for Angular"?

Answer (score 6):

The point here is loose coupling: in your architecture with only one class used to represent both the API response and the user-facing data what are you going to do when:

1. The requirements change for what is displayed to the user, but the API doesn't change?
2. The API changes but the requirements for what is to be displayed to the user don't?

In both cases, you've now got a change which should affect only one layer, but ends up affecting more than one because you've coupled them by using the same class.

And before you go and blindly split every class into two and have a no-op mapper converting between the two, stop and think about how likely each of the scenarios listed above are **for your project** and where the balance lies.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I do see the benefit of having dto and model separate for the reasons you mentioned. But as you also mentioned, for my project I do not have difference in what comes from api and what I show on the page, so if that is the case I ideally do not need two type of classes. Also, what I return from my backend api are anyways the data I want to show on front end

Comment: @PawanNogariya, to expand on this answer, API requests and responses are typically interfaces in TypeScript. You can remove the mapping layer if the model classes also implement the API request interfaces. Now you can pass your models to anything needing the API request interfaces. This is just good ol' fashioned object-oriented programming and polymorphism here. Nothing special because it's an Angular frontend or TypeScript.

Comment: Today we learned: "enterprise" patterns are not necessarily appropriate for a toy project.

Answer (score 0):

This best practice guide seems to be written from a front end only point of view.

If you only write the front end, then you can't reuse the backends `Models`. So you have to write your own models, but call them `DTOs`. your front end logic goes in its own model which you call a `Model` but the backend would call a `ViewModel`

You don't really want to map your DTO directly to a Model. You should have a ViewModel for the entire page which might have data from several DTOs/Models plus extra bits about the state of dropdowns or darkmode/lightmode etc

Calling models ViewModels makes more sense to me, they are tightly coupled to your presentation layer.

eg.

```
SelectionPageViewModel
{
   CustomerDTO selectedCustomer
   CustomerDTO[] customers
   marketingOptIn = true
   OnClick() => {
     //do stuff
   }
}
```

You have no need for a CustomerViewModel/CustomerModel which is the same as a CustomerDTO so creating them would not be best practice. You DO need viewmodels for your pages to encapsulate the data (which may include DTO objects) and functionality of the View

If your view is so simple as to not need any extra data or functionality at all, you could just use the DTO. But I think I would make a ViewModel anyway, You are bound to need it. But I would just wrap a DTO rather than creating an identical object.

```
CustomerViewModel
{
    CustomerDTO customer
}
```

The alternate approach of using inheritance is out of style these days, but would also alleviate the need for a duplicate object and mapping

```
CustomerViewModel : CustomerDTO
{

}
```

the recommendation to "probably extend the DTO and format some fields" I think is just wrong. The place for that kind of thing is in the view Itself. eg.

```
<div> {{customer.date | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </div>
```

Comment: *"seems to be written from a front end only point of view"* - I thought Angular is a client side framework, so this does not seem to be very astonishing

Comment: sure but affects the naming of things